# Disable H + Click in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shortcuts

I drag my canvas across my screen a lot, using the Hand Tool (H). The problem is, I tend to click immediately after going to this tool. This triggers the H + Left Click shortcut for a zoomed canvas selection process.

Not only does this make me have to wait for the zoom, but it also moves the mouse selection over to the middle of the screen.

I want to disable the H + Left click functionality or shortcut. Is there a way to do so?

I'm using adobe Photoshop CC from 2014

Alternatively, is there a way to enable middle mouse button canvas dragging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you try you movement around the document with the simply Spacebar + Left Click & Drag? It wont trigger the H+LC combo.